# Adding count constraint in lpSolveAPI R

Tags: r, optimization, lpsolve

I'm trying to dive into optimization and have been messing around with lpSolveAPI package. Example will demonstrate my simple setup.

data (every row holds different variable):

```
dput(test.df)
    structure(list(objective = c(-0.162235888601422, -0.168597233981057, 
    -0.165558234725657, -0.156096491294958, -0.15294764940114), constrain1 = c(1.045, 
    1.259, 1.792, 2.195, 2.802)), .Names = c("objective", "constrain1"
    ), row.names = c(NA, -5L), class = "data.frame")

library(lpSolveAPI)
```

create empty model, with 5 variables (rows in test.df) and I want to maximize my objective.

```
test.lp <- make.lp(0, NROW(test.df))
set.objfn(test.lp, test.df$objective)
lp.control(test.lp,sense='max')
```

Lets add few constraints.

```
add.constraint(test.lp, test.df$constrain1, "=", 2)
add.constraint(test.lp, rep(1, nrow(test.df)), "=", 1)
set.bounds(test.lp, upper = rep(0.5, nrow(test.df)))
set.bounds(test.lp, lower = rep(0, nrow(test.df)))
RowNames <- c("constraint1", "constraint2")
ColNames <- paste0("var", seq(1, nrow(test.df)))
dimnames(test.lp) <- list(RowNames, ColNames)
```

I would like to create onemore constraint, which would be that use only x number of variables in solve. So if I set it up to 2, it would create optimal solution with 2 of those variables. I have tried `set.type = "binary"` but that wasn't successful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here some code that shows how to apply the technique mentioned by @ErwinKalvelagen to lpSolveAPI in R. The main point is to add additional binary variables to the problems.

```
library(lpSolveAPI)
fun1 <- function(n=3) {
    nx <- 5

    # set up lp
    lprec <- make.lp(0, 2*nx) # one var for the value x(i) and one var y(i) binary if x(i) > 0
    set.objfn(lprec, c(-0.162235888601422, -0.168597233981057, -0.165558234725657, -0.156096491294958, -0.15294764940114, rep(0, nx)))
    lp.control(lprec,sense='max')
    set.type(lprec, columns=seq(nx+1,2*nx), "binary") # y(i) are binary vars

    # add constraints as in the question
    set.bounds(lprec, upper=rep(0.5, nx), columns=seq(1,nx)) # lpsolve implicitly assumes x(i) >= 0, so no need to define bounds for that
    add.constraint(lprec, c(1.045, 1.259, 1.792, 2.195, 2.802, rep(0, nx)), "=", 2)
    add.constraint(lprec, c(rep(1, nx), rep(0, nx)), "=", 1)

    # additional constraints as suggested by @ErvinKarvelagen
    for (i in seq(1,nx)) add.constraint(lprec, xt=c(1, -0.5), type="<=", rhs=0, indices=c(i, nx+i)) # x(i)<=y(i)*0.5
    add.constraint(lprec, c(rep(0,nx), rep(1,nx)), "<=", n) # sum(y(i))<=2 (if set to 3, it finds a solution)

    # solve and print solution
    status <- solve(lprec)
    if(status!=0) stop("no solution found, error code=", status)
    sol <- get.variables(lprec)[seq(1, nx)]
    return(sol)
}
```

Note, however, that the problem becomes infeasible if you require that only two x(i) are greater zero. You need at least three to meet the constraints given. (this is done by the parameter n). Also note that `set.row` is more efficient than `add.constraint` in the long term.

Elaborating @ErwinKalvelagen's second comment, another approach is to simply take every n out of the 5 possible variable combination and solve for these n variables. Translated to R code, this would become

```
fun2 <- function(n=3) {
    nx <- 5

    solve_one <- function(indices) {
        lprec <- make.lp(0, n) # only n variables
        lp.control(lprec,sense='max')
        set.objfn(lprec, c(-0.162235888601422, -0.168597233981057, -0.165558234725657, -0.156096491294958, -0.15294764940114)[indices])
        set.bounds(lprec, upper=rep(0.5, n))
        add.constraint(lprec, c(1.045, 1.259, 1.792, 2.195, 2.802)[indices],"=", 2)
        add.constraint(lprec, rep(1, n), "=", 1)
        status <- solve(lprec)
        if(status==0) 
            return(list(obj = get.objective(lprec), ind=indices, sol=get.variables(lprec)))
        else
            return(list(ind=indices, obj=-Inf))
    }

    sol <- combn(nx, n, FUN=solve_one, simplify=FALSE)
    best <- which.max(sapply(sol, function(x) x[["obj"]]))
    return(sol[[best]])
}
```

Both codes return the same solution, however the first solution is much faster:

```
library(microbenchmark)
microbenchmark(fun1(), fun2(), times=1000, unit="ms")
#Unit: milliseconds
#   expr      min       lq      mean   median       uq       max neval
# fun1() 0.429826 0.482172 0.5817034 0.509234 0.563555  6.590409  1000
# fun2() 2.514169 2.812638 3.2253093 2.966711 3.202958 13.950398  1000
```

Comment: Thanks, will try to figure this one out.

Comment: In this case all variables still can be zeros.

Answer (score 0):

I think you want to add a constraint that limits the number of nonzero variables `x(i)` to be 2. Counting can not really be done in an LP but it can be formulated as a MIP.

A standard formulation would be to introduce binary variables `y(i)` with:

```
x(i) <= y(i)*xup(i)      (implication: y(i)=0 => x(i)=0)
sum(i, y(i)) <= 2     
0 <= x(i) <= xup(i)      (bounds)
y(i) in {0,1}            (binary variables)
```

For larger problems this can be much more efficient than solving each possible combination. Although `k=2` out of `N` is not that bad: `N choose k = N*(N-1)/2` possible combinations.

Comment: This looks interesting. Could you write that to my example? I have no idea how to use that in my solution. I'm sure it works, but I'm limited to test it.

Comment: May be you can elaborate what you don't understand so we can give a better answer.

Comment: Basically, I have no idea how to turn that to R language (I'm fairly new to R, but that doesn't look R code) and add it as constraint to my problem. Will try to look package instructions how to do it. Thank You for your answer.

Comment: It is not R. I tried to write things down in mathematical notation as that is better in showing the concepts of this formulation. The constraints are very simple so you should have no problems in transcribing this into R.